# Calculate energy of an integral of a function

Tags: integration, exponential-function, fourier-transform

This is part of a homework so I'm not looking for whole answers, only something to get me started.

I want to calculate the energy of the function s:

$s(t)=\int_{-2}^{3} e^{5i{\pi}t{\nu}}  \,d\nu$

I know the energy of a function is the integral of the squared function when $t\in[-\infty, \infty]$. The problem is that I can't seem to get anywhere if I just square the function and integrate, as the calculations get very messy.

There is a tip given that I should keep the conservation of energy in mind. I know that the energy of a function is conserved when doing a Fourier transform. So am I on the right path if I first take the Fourier transform of the function and then calculate the energy of the transform-function?

Comment: Have you tried to perform the integral that defines $s(t)$ first to get a closed expression for $s(t)$?

Comment: Yes I have. Otherwise I wouldn't know that it gets messy

Comment: By [Parseval's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parseval%27s_identity) the energy of the Fourier transform is the same as the energy of the original function (up to a factor depending on how one defines the Fourier transform). So yes, you can calculate the Fourier transform and then calculate the energy of that.